# Rational class to handle fractions

Tags: performance, beginner, object-oriented, objective-c, rational-numbers

I am very new to Objective-C as well as objected oriented programming, and in a book I am studying from there is an exercise in which I was supposed to create a class called `Rational`, that has hidden data members called numerator and denominator, and methods to add, multiply, subtract and divide the Rational objects (the objects are just fractions) together.  For some reason when I run the program it becomes extremely slow when calculating. I am using ARC on X-Code, and I am wondering if it has to do with memory management issues.

Here is the .m file of the class:

```
#import "Rational.h"
@interface Rational (privateMethods)

-(int) gcd:(int) a: (int) b;
-(Rational*) simplifyFraction:(Rational*)fraction;

@end


@implementation Rational

@synthesize numerator, denominator;

-(Rational*) multiplyFraction:(Rational *)fraction1 :(Rational *)fraction2{

    fraction1.numerator = fraction1.numerator * fraction2.numerator;

    fraction1.denominator = fraction1.denominator * fraction2.denominator;

    fraction1 = [self simplifyFraction:fraction1];

    return fraction1;
}

-(Rational*) addFraction:(Rational *)fraction1 :(Rational *)fraction2{

    Rational * returnFraction = [[Rational alloc] init];

    fraction1.numerator = fraction1.numerator*fraction2.denominator;

    fraction2.numerator = fraction2.numerator *fraction1.denominator;

    fraction1.denominator = fraction1.denominator*fraction2.denominator;

    fraction2.denominator = fraction1.denominator;

    returnFraction.numerator = fraction1.numerator + fraction2.numerator;

    returnFraction.denominator = fraction1.denominator;

    returnFraction = [self simplifyFraction:returnFraction];

    return returnFraction;

}

-(Rational*) subtractFraction:(Rational *)fraction1 :(Rational *)fraction2{

    Rational * returnFraction = [[Rational alloc] init];

    fraction1.numerator = fraction1.numerator*fraction2.denominator;

    fraction2.numerator = fraction2.numerator *fraction1.denominator;

    fraction1.denominator = fraction1.denominator*fraction2.denominator;

    fraction2.denominator = fraction1.denominator;

    returnFraction.numerator = fraction1.numerator - fraction2.numerator;

    returnFraction.denominator = fraction1.denominator;

    returnFraction = [self simplifyFraction:returnFraction];

    return returnFraction;
}

-(Rational*) divideFraction:(Rational *)fraction1 :(Rational *)fraction2{

    Rational * returnFraction = [[Rational alloc] init];

    const int temp = fraction2.denominator;

    fraction2.denominator = fraction2.numerator;

    fraction2.numerator = temp;

    returnFraction.numerator = fraction1.numerator * fraction2.numerator;

    returnFraction.denominator = fraction2.denominator * fraction1.denominator;

    returnFraction = [self simplifyFraction:returnFraction];

    return returnFraction;
}

-(void) printObject:(Rational *)fraction{

    printf("%i/%i",fraction.numerator, fraction.denominator);

    printf("\n");
}

-(void) printRoundedFloat:(Rational *)fraction{

    float number = (float)fraction.numerator/fraction.denominator;

    printf("%f", number);

    printf("\n");
}


-(int)gcd:(int)a :(int)b{

    if (b==0) {

        return a;

    }

    else

        return [self gcd:b :a%b];
}

-(Rational*) simplifyFraction:(Rational *)fraction{

    if (fraction.denominator == 0) {

        NSLog(@"ERROR: YOU CAN NOT HAVE ZERO IN THE DENOMINATOR");

}

    else{

        int i = fraction.numerator > fraction.denominator ? fraction.numerator:fraction.denominator;

        while (i>1) {

            if (fraction.numerator % i == 0 && fraction.denominator%i==0) {

                fraction.numerator/=i;

                fraction.denominator/=i;

            }

            --i;

        }

    }

    return fraction;

}

-(void) dealloc{
}

@end
```

Here is the Main.m file of the program:

```
import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

import "Rational.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Rational * newFraction = [[Rational alloc] init];
        Rational * otherFraction = [[Rational alloc] init];

        newFraction.numerator = 1;
        newFraction.denominator = 25;
        printf("Fraction 1 is: ");
        [newFraction printObject:newFraction];


        otherFraction.numerator = 1;
        otherFraction.denominator = 5;
        printf("Fraction 2 is:  ");
        [otherFraction printObject:otherFraction];

        printf("\nThe Fractions Added togeher are: ");
        id number = [newFraction addFraction:newFraction :otherFraction];
        [number printObject:number];
        printf("Rounded: ");
        [number printRoundedFloat:number];

        printf("\nThe Fractions subtracted are: ");
        number = [number subtractFraction:newFraction :otherFraction];
        [number printObject:number];
        printf("Rounded: ");
        [number printRoundedFloat:number];

        printf("\nThe Fractions multiplied are: ");
        number = [number multiplyFraction:newFraction :otherFraction];
        [number printObject:number];
        printf("Rounded: ");
        [number printRoundedFloat:number];

        printf("\nThe Fractions divided are: ");
        number = [number divideFraction:newFraction :otherFraction];
        [number printObject:number];
        printf("Rounded:  ");
        [number printRoundedFloat:number];
    }

    return 0;
```

Comment: Memory management *could* be the issue here; but can you give us a clear definition of what you mean by 'it becomes extremely slow'. Is this during the first pass, just in specific messages, do you have to run it a few times ? Also, perhaps try just disabling arc and see what that does ? This question has instructions on how to do this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837024/how-to-disable-xcode4-2-automatic-reference-counting

Comment: Each method runs fine individually, but when I call them all in the main, it takes about 2 seconds for both the multiplication and division to compute.. I've tried disabling arc and adding release statements, but it is still slow. I also tried it on another computer to assure it is not a hardware issue. It seems strange to take so long since the program is so small..

Answer (score 5):

```
@interface Rational (privateMethods)

-(int) gcd:(int) a: (int) b;
-(Rational*) simplifyFraction:(Rational*)fraction;

@end
```

This really should be a class extension rather than a private category.  A class extension means leaving the parenthesis out, and perhaps more importantly it means if we add a method to the interface here and don't implement it, the IDE will give us a warning.  Although honestly, it probably simply shouldn't exist at all--and we don't even necessarily need to declare the methods here even.

The `gcd` function, which should be named `greatestCommonDenominator` instead, isn't necessarily specific to fractions.  It can exist as a regular C function outside the class.  And honestly, I don't have a problem with exposing the function in the header file.

Anyway, to make it a regular C-function outside the class, just remove all of the existing stuff outside the `@interface` and `@implementation` sections, and write the function as such (above the `@interface`):

```
int greatestCommonDenominator(int a, int b) {
    if (b==0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return greatestCommonDenominator(b, a%b);
    }
}
```

---

The other method, `simplifyFraction:`, shouldn't take an argument.  Instead, it should simplify `self`... the instance which called the method.

In fact, this logic should be applied to almost every method in your class.  Our instances methods should use `self` in some way.  If we're not using `self`, it should be a class method.

---

```
-(void) printObject:(Rational *)fraction{

    printf("%i/%i",fraction.numerator, fraction.denominator);

    printf("\n");
}

-(void) printRoundedFloat:(Rational *)fraction{

    float number = (float)fraction.numerator/fraction.denominator;

    printf("%f", number);

    printf("\n");
}
```

It's a pretty hard and fast rule in OOP that objects shouldn't "print" themselves.  Instead, we return a string, and let whoever is using the object do with that string whatever it wants.  Both of these methods should be removed, and instead, we can offer:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i/%i", self.numerator, self.denominator];
}
```

And rather than returning some special format for the string representation of the float value, why don't we just turn it into a float value and return that value?

```
- (float)floatValue {
    return (float)self.numerator/(float)self.denominator;
}
```

We can also do this for `double`, and potentially for integer values as well.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to note here is that for some reason you coded up a `gcd` function, but do not utilize it in your `simplifyFraction` method.

By definition of gcd, it returns the greatest common divisor. Therefore, to simplify a fraction, you need simply to divide both the numerator and denominator by the gcd(numerator, denominator).

This would simplify your code a bit, make it more readable, and probably increase its speed.

Also, your division method is only made more complicated by having code such as:

```
returnFraction.numerator = fraction1.numerator * fraction2.numerator;
```

when intuitively it should be:

```
returnFraction.numerator = fraction1.numerator * fraction2.denominator;
```

I would eliminate the temp variable and essentially duplicate the style of the multiplication method to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a flash of inspiration, although possibly not related.

What happens if you change this method signature:

```
-(void) printObject:(Rational *)fraction{

    printf("%i/%i",fraction.numerator, fraction.denominator);

    printf("\n");
}
```

to

```
-(void) printObject
{
    printf("%i/%i",self.numerator, self.denominator);

    printf("\n");
}
```

And then

```
[newFraction printObject:newFraction];
```

to

```
[newFraction printObject];
```

And so on...

Seems odd that you're passing the object to a message that belongs to the object you're passing.

Comment: Although this didn't speed it up at all, I really appreciate this. I am new to OOP, and your code helped me understand the concept of self a lot better. I didn't realize that self would refer to the object that had been initialized. Thanks.

Comment: In fact the original form of the method did not use self at all so should have been a class method.  However, rather than having a method called `printObject` why not override `description`?

Comment: We really shouldn't be printing objects.  JeremyP is right--the correct solution is overriding `description`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be modifying the objects passed to the methods. If the user does not expect this, it could cause strange behavior later.

```
-(void) addFraction:(Rational *)fraction1 :(Rational *)fraction2
{
    const int num1 = fraction1.numerator * fraction2.denominator;
    const int num2 = fraction2.numerator * fraction1.denominator;

    self.numerator = num1 + num2;
    self.denominator = fraction1.denominator * fraction2.denominator;

    [self simplifyFraction:self];
}
```